# Is there an objective, external reality according to quantum physics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurement-problem

In quantum physics, a particle can be in a superposition of two states until it is measured. In other words, the aforementioned particle doesn't *have* a definite state until it is "looked at" (measured). Since certain properties (i.e., an electron's position) of a particle aren't well defined until they are  measured, does this mean that quantum objects don't possess these properties, unless they are looked at? Do quantum objects even *exist* without an observer? Since macroscopic things are made of quantum particles, does the moon stop existing when no one is looking at it, since its particles don't have a definite position, momentum, etc.? Do the answers to these questions depend on the interpretation of quantum physics being used?

I guess my main question is this: Is there an external, objective reality that exists even when it is not being measured?

Comment: First of all, these questions aren't really under the scope of physics. Science tells you what Nature does, and only offers metaphors of why and how. Second, ask yourself why you find it so weird that particles don't have definite momentum and position. So what? Momentum and position are made up concepts which we use to accurately describe results of experiments. So is the wave function. Quantum physics is really no weirder than any other physics theory, it's just slightly less intuitive and because of that people scrutinize it in ways they never bother to scrutinize all the other theories.

Comment: @DanielSank   Ok, fair enough. So my main question--Is there an external, observer independent reality--isn't under the scope of physics? Is that right?

Comment: I would say @DanielSank is adopting an 'empiricist' interpretation of science: basically if you can't answer your question through experiment then it's not science. It's a reasonable enough position, but it's far from universally accepted.

Comment: @MarkA: I think it's universally accepted that "science" deals with things which are falsifiable. As far as I can tell, that is congruent with "can be checked through experiment." That said, trying to understand what is and isn't "on-topic" on this site boggles the mind. All that aside, I think my point about subjecting "simpler" theories to the same philosophical inspection as we do to quantum mechanics is a good and relevant one.

Comment: @Jmfig314: I would say the question you're asking isn't even well formed. What does "observer independent reality" mean to you? I challenge you to even come up with a reasonably good scientific definition of "reality". This is quickly going to become philosophy, by the way, so we should stop doing this on a physics Q&A site. If you post on reddit/askscience I'll probably see it.

Comment: @DanielSank. That was Popper's definition of science, and no, in my experience it is far from universally accepted (although I think it's a pretty good one myself). I agree your point about simpler theories is good and relevant, and I agree this is quickly going to turn into philosophy (if it isn't already)...

Comment: @MarkA: When you say that definition is far from universally accepted, do you mean by people in general or by practicing scientists? I'm really curious about this, because as far as I know, all scientists I know would say that falsifiability is a great criterion by which to decide whether or not to call something "science".

Comment: @DanielSank - A large number of scientists. Scientists are fine with philosophers so long as the latter keep their worries to the number of angels that can dance on the point of a pin. Scientists bristle when philosophers argue that science is fundamentally wrong because per the way scientists do science, seeing a red herring is proof that all ravens are black. Scientists tend to see such arguments as red herrings.

Comment: With regard to scientists rejecting Popper's falsification, Kuhn's paradigm shifts, and Feyerabend's whatever, look to Feynman, Sokol, and a host of others: *Philosophy of science is about as useful to scientists as ornithology is to birds.* If philosophers' view of science was the correct view, physics educators would be teaching 16 year olds to use general relativity to solve a block sliding down a ramp problem because general relativity (and quantum mechanics) falsified Newtonian mechanics.

Comment: @DanielSank: "I think it's universally accepted that 'science' deals with things which are falsifiable. As far as I can tell, that is congruent with 'can be checked through experiment'." Does it refer to the theories about what is going on inside BHs? Or to the W boson in beta decay being 80x more massive than the particle that it was created from, and whose lifespan is too short for anybody to be able to verify this claim? Or virtual particles whose job is to deliver messages? So 'science", as you called it, 'deals' with anything it fancies (as well as it claims what it wishes to ...).

Comment: @DanielSank: sorry for the delay. My answer was too long for a comment, too off-topic for a separate question... Not sure what to do in these situations but in the end I wrote it down in a chat-room ('How do physicists define science?' - not sure how to link...), so you can look it up there if you are still curious~

Comment: Alright then. I guess this is more of a philosophy question then a physics question. Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've just started answering these sort of questions with "there is an external reality $\textit{in the quantum sense}$, but not in the standard classical sense that you know of". When people ask what does that mean I tell them that they need to learn QM to understand, which is the only honest answer I think.

Comment: Is it my imagination or is there a supposition somewhere in this discussion that the "observer" constitutes something separate from the "universe"? According to the usual naturalist/physicalist assumptions in science (no supernatural "souls", etc.) there isn't. It's all just matter, the observer is just a chunk of matter. If it's all just matter then to talk of the "observer" and "universe" as distinct is kind of silly, no?

Answer (score 3):

A superposition is a perfectly valid state in quantum mechanics. It simply doesn't have a correspondence in classical physics, which is the result of quantum mechanics (and not the other way around!).

> "In other words, the aforementioned particle doesn't have a definite state until it is "looked at" (measured)."

Yes, the particle (or better "the quantum system") does have a definite state: it's the superposition of two or more eigenstates.

> "Since certain properties (i.e., an electron's position) of a particle aren't well defined until they are measured"

They are perfectly well defined at all times. It's the act of a STRONG measurement which reduces the state to a pure state. There are weak measurements which do not. After the measurement the state is equally well defined, it's just not the same state as the system had before the measurement.

All of this is perfectly "objective", it's just very counterintuitive to those who can't accept that the world is not classical. The world was NEVER classical, we merely have been looking at the world using the wrong description until we discovered the right one approx. 80 and some years ago.

> "Do quantum objects even exist without an observer?"

No more and no less than a falling tree makes a sound when nobody listens. That's an incorrectly posed question even in classical physics.

Comment: Alright, I think I get it now. Thanks for clearing up my confusion.

Answer (score 2):

The question you ask is a tough one and everyone has his own opinion about the answer (look at the comments of your question). In particular, one has to adopt a more or less clear philosophical position about what science ought to tell us in order to reply.

That being said, the decoherence programme tries to address some of the questions you wonder about. In particular, classicality is supposed to emerge via a "measurement by the environment" that projects a quantum system that ought to behave classically (like the Schrodinger's cat) onto a (quasi-orthonormal) pointer basis that so happens to correspond to the classical observables we are used to (e.g. a phase space projector or the dead or alive states for the cat).

In this process of *einselection*, it is often thought that there is not really an objective way of determining the actual pointer states.

Now, quite recently Zurek et al. have proposed a solution to the idea of objective pointer states (that has been quite acknowledged in the literature) which they have called [quantum Darwinism](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5082).

My contribution would not be complete if I didn't give you a reference claiming that there is problem with the decoherence programme and in particular with the idea of quantum Darwinism. More about it [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4126).

Answer (score 2):

> In quantum physics, a particle can be in a superposition of two states
>   until it is measured. In other words, the aforementioned particle
>   doesn't have a definite state until it is "looked at" (measured).

A superposition state is a state. So a particle in such a state does have a state before being measured.

> Since certain properties (i.e., an electron's position) of a particle
>   aren't well defined until they are measured, does this mean that
>   quantum objects don't possess these properties, unless they are looked
>   at?

No. It means that the particle doesn't have a single position. Rather there are multiple instances of it at different positions. Those instances can interact with one another in interference experiments, which is why you can't understand what it is doing by considering it as having only a single position. See

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0104033

> Do quantum objects even exist without an observer? Since macroscopic
>   things are made of quantum particles, does the moon stop existing when
>   no one is looking at it, since its particles don't have a definite
>   position, momentum, etc.?

For a large non-isolated system like the moon, interactions with other systems prevent it from undergoing interference on a macroscopic scale. It does exist in multiple versions but you can't see the other versions, see

http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9612037

> Do the answers to these questions depend on the interpretation of
>   quantum physics being used?

Different "interpretations" of quantum mechanics make different claims about what is happening in reality. So they ought to be treated as different physical theories, not interpretations. Quantum mechanics without the collapse postulate implies the Everett interpretation:

http://www.daviddeutsch.org.uk/many-minds-interpretations-of-quantum-mechanics/

Other interpretations may have different implications about how the world works but they are usually ambiguous about what exists and some are apparently inconsistent or otherwise unviable.

> I guess my main question is this: Is there an external, objective
>   reality that exists even when it is not being measured?

Yes.

Comment: >For a large non-isolated system like the moon, interactions with other systems prevent it from undergoing interference<

What do you mean by isolation? Let's say I were to isolate the moon from every other system. This would involve taking it out of the universe because no matter what I do, I cannot eliminate the spacetime curvature it will cause.

Comment: Non-isolated means that information about the moon's state is copied into other systems, such as light reflecting off its surface, on timescales that are very short compared to those we're interested in.

Comment: Yes but my question was specifically about Gravity. You see macroscopic objects have far more of it exerted on other systems rather than quantum particles, which can also be considered one of the reasons we observe macroscopic reality to be not in superposition. If quantum particles had significant gravity, maybe we wouldn't observe interference.